# How do I print dicts through multiple files,

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

so,I need to print a dict.Heres what my file2.py file looks like

```
import json

dict = {}

file1 = open("dictfile.txt","w")
file1.write(json.dumps(dict))
file1.close()
```

then my main file where I use this

```
from api import dict 

dict["smthng"] = "hi"


print(dict["smthng"])
```

it prints hi,but my dictfile.txt looks like

```
{}
```

normal,but not what I was expecting.I want it to save the value assigned in main.py,but do it from file2.py.

Comment: Your program says: "Write an empty dict in json to a file, then update the dict with a new key, then print the value"

Comment: how would I go with doing that from file2.py without knowing the value

Comment: Do you mean that you want code that writes to `dictfile.txt` *after* your main does the update with `"hi"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}

file1 = open("dictfile.txt","w")
file1.write(json.dumps(dict))
file1.close()
```

This is not doing anything except putting `{}` into the txt file.

```
from api import dict 

dict["smthng"] = "hi"


print(dict["smthng"])
```

This is not doing anything except assigning a key and value to an empty dictionary that you got from file2.py. And I'm assuming file2.py is api.py. So what I think you want to do is in file2.py you want to create a function where you pass in a key and value then file2.py will write that data in a txt file. Then in your main.py you read that file.

**file2.py**

```
import json
def writeInfo(**kwargs)
    dict = kwargs
    file1 = open("dictfile.txt","w")
    file1.write(json.dumps(dict))
    file1.close()
```

**main.py**

```
from file2 import writeInfo
writeInfo(a="how",b="to")
```

Now you can read the file.